# Using instance method inside the init

Tags: python, class, oop

I wonder whether it is a bad practice to define instance attributes with calling instance methods?.

```
class MyClass:
    

    def __init__(self, attr1, attr2):
        self.attr1 = attr1
        self.attr2 = attr2

    def func(self):
        """
        Performs computationally expensive operations using self.attr1 and self.attr2
        """

    def func2(self):
        """
         Needs result of the instance method func()
        """

    def func3(self):
        """
        Needs result of the instance method func()
        """

    def disp(self):

        """
        Use results of func2 and func3 to display something
        """


if __name__ == '__main__':

    obj = MyClass(attr1=5,attr2=5)
    obj.disp()
```

Above, the `func()` will be called twice, rather than that what I would like to do is to store its result and call it only once and use its stored values as many times as needed by another instance method inside the class. Naively I just added another attribute inside the `__init__` and defined it via `func()`.

```
class MyClass:


    def __init__(self, attr1, attr2):
        self.attr1 = attr1
        self.attr2 = attr2
        self.invariant = self.func()

    def func(self):
        """
        Performs computationally expensive operations using self.attr1 and self.attr2
        """

    def func2(self):
        """
         Uses self.invariant when it needs the result of func()
        """

    def func3(self):
        """
        Uses self.invariant when it needs the result of func()
        """
     .
     .
     .
```

If this is a bad practice how can I handle the problem more efficiently? It just feels a bit weird calling the instance method inside `__init__`.

Comment: "It just feels a bit weird calling the instance method inside `__init__`"—why? Your example is too abstract to really be useful, but it is quite common to call methods in `__init__()`. It is also common to save the value the first time you call `func()` (e.g. in a `_func` attribute) and reuse the saved value later if it doesn't change. This has the added benefit of only running `func()` when you need it instead of for every object created. Anyway, this is primarily opinion-based and is likely to be closed.

Comment: perhaps [function caching](https://book.pythontips.com/en/latest/function_caching.html#function-caching)

Comment: @Chris Probably wrong but for some reason, I associate _init_ as the initialization of the object, feels like calling the instance method w/o the instance itself fully initialized.

Comment: @ZekiZeybek, in some cases it might make sense to do. In others, not so much. Your example contains no information about what the methods do so it's impossible to say whether it makes sense in this case.

Comment: @Chris Can you provide me with some directions or keywords to look up in order to achieve what you have said about not calling the ```func()``` for every objected created but when only it is needed.

Comment: @ZekiZeybek, if you're on Python 3.8+ check out [`functools.cached_property`](https://docs.python.org/dev/library/functools.html#functools.cached_property). If not, search for "python cache method result" or similar. There are a bunch of patterns, including roll-your-own where you'd do the computation and save the result as `self._func` if `self._func is None` and simply return `self._func` if it isn't.

Answer (score 0):

By itself, Python does not forbid it. It is up to the programmer to make sure to never call a function using an attribute before defining the attribute. For that reason, people coming from the Java world (including the excellent PyCharm IDE) recommend to define all attributes in `__init__` without calling any instance method.

For that reason I think of those rules as *best practices rules that should be obeyed until we have a reason to break them*. Here you have a real reason to encapsulate a heavy computation in a method, and call that method at object initialization because it is really part of the initialization. My advice is just *do it*. It is of course easy to use a workaround but the real question is about readability and maintainability which IMHO are the most important rules for Python.

TL/DR: If calling that method from `__init__` make the code more readable or more easy to maintain, then it should be done. But of course this is only my opinion. And teams could have *private rules* forbidding it. In that case, as usual, the local team rules should be obeyed.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, I would not call myself a proper java developer but "people coming from the Java world"  that was the reason why it felt a bit weird to use instance method inside the init.

Answer (score 0):

First thing it is not a bad practice considering this is the last statement in init. The issue is for anyone updating the func in future assuming it is not called from init and creating an object of the same class in func thereby going in endless loop. You might add a comment in func saying 'called from **init**'

So there are two things here. func is either private or not. One of the good practice is make func private. So just prefix func with

```
__func__
```

.

If you have an argument that it is not private (which means you can call it directly from main) then don't club it with init call it separately even if it is a pain.

```
if __name__ == '__main__':

    obj = MyClass(attr1=5,attr2=5)
    obj.func()
    obj.disp()
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply, I am still very new to OOP principles and will definitely look for private public stuff.